# Changing checkmark color of a checkbox in a WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, controltemplate

I am trying to change the color of a checkmark of a checkbox in a WPF List View. I got the following XAML Code from another post. Unfortuantely I am not familar enough with the whole framework to understand where exacatly I need to add that in my ListView. Is anyone able to give me some hint. Many thanks in adavance.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Path x:Name="Equis" Opacity="0" Stroke="Red" Fill="Red" Stretch="UniformToFill" StrokeThickness="20" Data="M 30,100 L 80,140 L 160,60" Margin="0,0,2,2" />
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Equis" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Equis" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here the XAML of the checkbox in the GridViewColumn (works fine)

```
<GridViewColumn Header="HeaderName" Width="35">

    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxName" IsChecked="{Binding Object}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Actually I do not know were the put the code above (it is just an example from another post) in my XAML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the ControlTemplate part of the Style that you show.  You need to give it a key with `x:Key="MyCheckBoxTemplate"`.  Then you can apply it to the CheckBox in your own CellTemplate with `Template="{StaticResource MyCheckBoxTemplate}"`.

A full worked example is below.  In this I changed the sample ControlTemplate in your question because it draws a rather nasty big red splodge when the CheckBox is selected.  I made it draw a much smaller checkmark in red:

[image: What it looks like]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="MyCheckBoxTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Path x:Name="Equis" 
                      Stroke="Red" 
                      StrokeThickness="3" 
                      Height="17" Width="19" Stretch="None" 
                      Margin="0,0,2,2"
                      Opacity="1"
                      >
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="3,10">
                                <LineSegment Point="8,14" />
                                <LineSegment Point="16,6" />
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Equis" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="Equis" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Checked" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShortName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HeaderName" Width="35">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxName" Template="{StaticResource MyCheckBoxTemplate}"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp11
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateProducts();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        private void CreateProducts()
        {
            Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
            {
                new Product{ShortName="My First Product", ID = 1},
                new Product{ShortName="My Second Product", ID = 2, IsChecked= true},
                new Product{ShortName="My Third Product", ID = 3},
                new Product{ShortName="My Fourth Product", ID = 4, IsChecked = true},
                new Product{ShortName="My Fifth Product", ID = 5}
           };
        }
    }

    public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string shortName;
        public string ShortName
        {
            get { return shortName; }
            set
            {
                shortName = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ShortName)));
            }
        }

        private int id;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                   new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ID)));
            }
        }

        private bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsChecked)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-template the entire control. Take a look at this example:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxName" IsChecked="{Binding Object}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <CheckBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="Red"/>
    </CheckBox.Resources>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                    <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

The colour of the checkmark is defined by the `OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph`, `OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph` and `OptionMark.Static.Glyph` resources. You can the `Color` of these to whatever you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Shall I add the <CheckBox> section inside the <ListView> or just as part of the <Window>?

Comment: @Norbert: Just replace your `CheckBox` element in the `CellTemplate` with mine in the answer.